# Select last 5 rows in join query SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, select, join

I am trying to bring the last 5 rows of the `Order` table based on `OrderDate` with the column name `firstname` from `Customer` table.

The below query displays all the values from the `Order` table instead of last 5 rows.

```
SELECT  
   A.[FirstName], B.[OrderId], B.[OrderDate], B.[TotalAmount], B.[OrderStatusId]
FROM  
   [schema].[Order] B 
OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 5  *
    FROM [schema].[Customer] A  
    WHERE B.[CustomerId] = 1 
      AND A.[CustomerId] = B.[CustomerId] 
   ORDER BY
      B.[OrderDate] DESC) A
```

Any mistake in my logic of using `TOP` and `DESC` ?

Comment: Everyone knows how to find the bottom 5. can someone please tell the error in the above query???

Comment: what is the output you are getting from your query ?

Comment: Do you need last five orders in the system or last five per customer?

Comment: @AshutoshArya : I get all the rows of Ordertable with the columnName from FirstName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the last 5 rows of `Order` table, why do you apply `TOP` to `Customer` table?

```
SELECT TOP 5 A.[FirstName],B.[OrderId],B.[OrderDate],B.[TotalAmount],B.[OrderStatusId]
FROM  [schema].[Order] B 
LEFT JOIN [schema].[Customer] A ON A.[CustomerId]=B.[CustomerId] 
WHERE B.[CustomerId]=1 
ORDER BY  B.[OrderDate] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(

    SELECT  A.[FirstName],
            B.[OrderId],
            B.[OrderDate],
            B.[TotalAmount],
            B.[OrderStatusId],
            ROWNUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.[OrderDate] DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM    [schema].[Order] B 
            OUTER APPLY
            (  
                SELECT  TOP 5  *
                FROM    [schema].[Customer] A  
                WHERE   B.[CustomerId]=1 
                        AND A.[CustomerId]=B.[CustomerId] 
                ORDER BY
                B.[OrderDate] DESC                  
            )     A
)

SELECT [FirstName],
       [OrderId],
       [OrderDate],
       [TotalAmount],
       [OrderStatusId] 
FROM   MyCTE
WHERE  RowNum <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use `OUTER APPLY`, I think of `row_number()` for such queries:

```
SELECT  A.[FirstName],B.[OrderId],B.[OrderDate],B.[TotalAmount],B.[OrderStatusId]
FROM  [schema].[Order] B join
      (select A.*, row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by OrderDate desc) as seqnum
       from [schema].[Customer] A
       where A.[CustomerId] = 1 -- AND A.[CustomerId]=B.[CustomerId] 
      ) A
      on A.[CustomerId] = B.[CustomerId] and seqnum <= 5;
```